# Determine Form Input Type On Server Side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, input, server-side, model-binding

I have a form with a field named description that can be either a text box or a select list depending on the input of previous form fields. How this works is if the values of the previous fields are a common scenario, we populate the description field as a select list with values stored in the database. If there are no matching scenarios in the database the user is allowed to type in their own description.

If the input type is a select list the submitted value is an integer (in string form) that can be used to query the database to get the description from the database. Otherwise we just use the text value submitted via the text box.

My question is: Once the form is submitted is there any way of determining the input type of the description field?

In my controller I was hoping to do something like this:

```
if(InputType == "SelectList")
{
    Description = model.Description;
}
else if (InputType == "TextBox")
{
    Description = GetDescriptionFromDB(model.Description);
}
```

I have considered checking to see if the description field parses to an integer, but that will not work if the user types in an integer to the text box. This is an internal app used by trained people who are not likely to enter junk values, but I still don't like to use logic that is dependent on what the user types in.  I have also considered using Javascript and a hidden field to pass along the input type, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

I am currently using modelbinding to get my submitted form values, but am open to other approaches.

**Edit:**

People are suggesting alternate approaches, most of which I have already considered. What I really want to know is whether information regarding input types are passed to the server when a form is posted or just data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a hidden field to the form that would track what type of input the description field is:

```
if(InputType == "SelectList")
{
    DescriptionInput = MyEnum.SelectList;
    Description = model.Description;
}
else if (InputType == "TextBox")
{
    DescriptionInput = MyEnum.TextBox;
    Description = GetDescriptionFromDB(model.Description);
}
```

Comment: My question states that I already considered that. I would need to use Javascript since the input type is decided dynamically. I was hoping for a pure server side solution, though I would use a hidden field and Javascript if that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="sel">
    <option class="default">Default</option>
</select>
```

Every Html Form Element in the form submit to server it's take it's value to server. If you choose the select then it's value are off-course going to server.

You just need to parse it and it will work.

```
If there are no matching scenarios in the database the user is allowed to type in their own description
```

I thing Queti's answer is correct. You can use hidden field and pass the ID of existing matching field.

Remember that this is unsafe so better option is you can check them on server too that is their anything exist in server or not. This way your code are sure for what input he make from user.

Comment: As I said to Queti my question states that I already considered using a hidden field. What I really want to know is if there is some way of determining server side only what the input type of the field is.

Comment: select submit with it's default value unless you have changed it. If user use one of the 2 way then you need to check the value that's all I thing to do. If someone are more logic based then I feel best option is consider javascript.